# string.indexof not working as expected

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I got a problem with the `string.IndexOf` method.
I have a string containing multiple substrings I want to extract.
Example:

```
key=muchdata&key=muchdata&key=muchdata
```

that is the simplified structure of the input string.
`muchdata` can contain every A-Za-z0-9 and special characters like !"§$%&/()=?

I would like to get the data between all `key=` strings.

First I wanted to use a regex but I wasn't able to create one that worked.
Then I thought about using `string.IndexOf`.
So I did something like this:

```
int start = input.IndexOf("key=");
int end = input.IndexOf("&key=");
string sub = input.Substring(start, end);
```

Unfortunately that didn't work as expected. Sometimes it even returned a substring but about 30 characters to long.
I built in some more code to check if `end == -1` if I reached the end so that I just got the last substring from `start` to the end of the whole string.

I really have no clue what to do next :(
What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the parameters of `Substring`. The second one *isn't* an index, it's a count...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using string operations, use classes designed for this

```
var coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("key=muchdata&key=muchdata&key2=muchdata");
var key = coll["key"];
```

Comment: In this example the variable "key" will have the value "muchdata, muchdata" as it takes and appends all values with a matching keyname (so the first two have the keyname "key"). Having unique keynames solves this of course.

Comment: Also a reference to System.Web must be added to the project first as simply having "using System.Web;" only seems to include some of the code available in the referenced DLL without the class HttpUtility.

Comment: hmm...the resulting code is a bit ugly but your method works the best so far. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `string.Split` to get all the values between `[&]key=`

```
var myValues
    = "key=muchdata&key=muchdata&key=muchdata".Split(new[] { "key=", "&key=" },
         StringSplitOptions.None);
```

The output of your string would be a string array:

```
muchdata
muchdata
muchdata
```

---

As for what you're currently doing, I think we'd need to see more of your code to figure out what's going wrong. You probably have those three lines of code in a loop of some sort to try and get each "substring".

My guess is that on the second go-around, you'd get `12` and `25` in `start` and `end`, respectively (for the example string you used). The `string.Substring` method takes a starting index and length, not a start and end. If you just plug `12` and `25` into that method, you'll get unexpected results:

```
&key=muchdata&key=muchdat
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do 
string sub = input.Substring(start + 4, end); since the start is the index at which Key= begins. So to get the substring you should adjust by the number of characters in Key=

Answer (score 0):

That's becase `IndexOf()` returns a position of the first character of a searched expression. So you need to add the length of the expression. Also, `Substring` takes a length as a second parameter, not ending index.

```
var startEx = "key=";
int start = input.IndexOf(startEx) + startEx.Length;
int end = input.IndexOf("&key=");
string sub = input.Substring(start , end - start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `Split` your text by `key=` and then remove all invalid characters with `LINQ:`

```
var str = "key=muchdata&key=muchdata&key=muchdata";
var result = str.Split(new string[] { "key=" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(word => new String(word.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray()))
             .ToList();
```

result should be `List<string>`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
string input="key=muchdata1&key=muchdata2&keys=muchdata3";
var data=input.Split(new[] { "&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
List<String> keyValues = new List<String>();
foreach(string d in data)
{
    if(d.StartsWith("key="))
    {
        keyValues.Add(d.Substring(4));
    }
}
//Access Values Here
foreach (string d in keyValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
Console.ReadKey();;
```